# Jquery Countdown timer for multiple events

Tags: jquery, countdown

Here is my problem. I am coding a website for a meeting hall. The client wants a countdown to the next meeting on the home page. I figured I would use The Jquery Countdown plugin on http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html as it has everything I need. But as the meeting hall has multiple meetings each day I need it to countdown to the next meeting on expiration. I know the dates and times of all the meetings each day but I don't know how I can switch to the next meeting on expiration. Any thoughts?

Comment: What format are the dates and times in? How do you access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a 40Kb solution like the Keith Wood's one. But, after 5 hours playing with code, I came up with this very versatile solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function countDown(eventID) {
        var $this, h, m, s;
        $this = $('#event'+eventID);
        s = parseInt($this.text().substr(6),10);
        m = parseInt($this.text().substr(3,5),10);
        h = parseInt($this.text().substr(0,2),10);
        s--;
        m = (s < 0) ? --m : m;
        h = (m < 0) ? --h : h;
        if (h < 0) {
            $this.css('display','none');
            $this.parent().slideUp('slow');
            $this.parent().remove();
        }
        s = (s < 0) ? 59 : s;
        m = (m < 0) ? 59 : m;
        $this.text(((h < 10) ? '0'+h : h)+':'+((m < 10) ? '0'+m : m)+':'+((s < 10) ? '0'+s : s));
        setTimeout('countDown('+eventID+')',1000);
        $('.counter').first().show();
    }

    $(document).ready( function() {
        var eventID = 0; 
        $('#nextEvents div').each( function () {
            var nextEventH = parseInt($(this).text().substring(0,2),10);
            var nextEventM = parseInt($(this).text().substring(3,5),10);
            var nextEventS = $(this).text().substring(5,7);
            nextEventH = (nextEventS === 'PM') ? nextEventH + 12 : nextEventH;
            nextEventS = 0;
            var curTime = new Date();
            //curTime = curTime.getHours()+':'+curTime.getMinutes()+':'+curTime.getSeconds();
            nextEventH = Math.abs(nextEventH - curTime.getHours());
            nextEventH = (nextEventH < 10) ? '0'+nextEventH : nextEventH;
            nextEventM = Math.abs(nextEventM - curTime.getMinutes());
            nextEventM = (nextEventM < 10) ? '0'+nextEventM : nextEventM;
            nextEventS = Math.abs(nextEventS - curTime.getSeconds());
            nextEventS = (nextEventS < 10) ? '0'+nextEventS : nextEventS;
            $(this).append("<div class='counter' id='event"+eventID+"' style='display:none; "+
                "position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:auto; height:auto; color:red; ' >"+
                nextEventH + ':' + nextEventM + ':' + nextEventS+"</div>");
            countDown(eventID);
            eventID++;
        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
   <div id='wrapper' style='position:relative; width:600px; height:400px; background-color:#366; color:#EEE; ' >
    <div id='nextEvents' >
     <div style='position:relative; width:100%; display:block; ' >05:12AM - Meeting with department heads</div>
     <div style='position:relative; width:100%; display:block; ' >05:13AM - Meeting with Department of Finances</div>
     <div style='position:relative; width:100%; display;block; ' >05:14AM - Meeting with Human Resources</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: What a Great and easy to use code. Thank you for your time! How can I make this so that I can add days as well? The meeting they have are set and so not change much. They are pretty much weekly meetings. like monday 5:00pm is always one meeting but tuesday 5:00 might be another

Comment: If you are able to, go ahead and vote my answer up and accept it as your chosen answer. I will recode it to include days as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The Countdown plugin has a parameter called onExpiry, which is a callback function that executes every time the Countdown reaches zero. Inside this function, you can (a) calculate the next meeting date, and (b) change the "until" field of the countdown instance to that value.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="countdown"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#countdown').countdown(
    {
        until: getNextMeeting(),
        onExpiry:
            function()
            {
                $(this).countdown("change", "until", getNextMeeting());
            }
    }
);

function getNextMeeting()
{
    // Based on the current time, figure out the next meeting time here:
    now = new Date();
    return now;
}
```

I've set up an example in jsfiddle that resets the time every 5 seconds. Of course, you'll want to adjust that to calculate actual meeting times:

http://jsfiddle.net/wXYSZ/

Hope this helps!